# How do I zoom in graph with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hi I'm working with matplotlab library and want to zoom in graph I made too see it more clearly.
Any ideas?

[pic of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jGpv.png)

[image: pic of graph i want to zoom in]

Comment: Please add your code as text, never as image. Note that matplotlib is without `h`. "Mat" comes from "matrix". Did you try `plt.xlim(-3,1)` to zoom in?

Answer (score 0):

In matplotlib you can zoom in the plot by specifying the x and y limits. For the case you have provided an example can be:

```
plt.xlim(-2.5, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 50)
```

If you only want to zoom in in the x axis use only the first line. Analogously you can zoom in only in the y axis by using the second line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the xlim and ylim unchanged then you can export the figure as a png using

```
plt.savefig()
```

you may also increase the dpi value.